# How can I view FPS in Skyrim?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I want to be able to see the FPS I'm running at, as it feels a bit low.

I've tried `tdt` in the console to no avail.

Comment: tdt definitely doesn't work for me either... might have been something that worked in beta?

Comment: tdt doesnt work for me either..

Comment: You can use the steam FPS counter (settings>In-game). If you don't own Skyrim on steam, you can add it as a non-steam game and the FPS counter will show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Install a tool like [FRAPS](http://www.fraps.com/) (free, but limited to 30 seconds of screen recording) or [RivaTuner](http://www.guru3d.com/index.php?page=rivatuner) (free) and you will be able to see the FPS of any game.

FRAPS can be used for showing your FPS, as well as recording your gameplay, but that will require you to buy the full version.

Comment: From what I've heard, wouldn't those slow Skyrim down? Especially FRAPS.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck: FRAPS only slows down the game when you are recording a video. Counting the amounts of frames per second and writing 2 numbers on the screen will not have any influence.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/24239

A self-described simple, bare-bones FPS counter. Does exactly what it says on the tin. I use it, I like it.

Has a couple extra features, too. There's a key to toggle it, a key to change the corner it appears in, and even a key to change the priority of the Skyrim process. Everything configurable through the INI.

It's an SKSE plugin, but apparently there's another way to use it if you don't want SKSE.